# Conexion a Base de datos .DBF usando C#

Tags: c#, oledb

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Windows Form y necesito conectarla a una base de datos con extensión .DBF.

Basándome en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227711/how-to-connect-to-dbf-database) pregunta y en [esta](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/) página he desarrollado el código siguiente:

```
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection
{
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:/ruta;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=usr;Password=pss;"
};

try
{
    Conn.Open();
}
catch (OleDbException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Conn.Close();
}
```

Esto me da en consola el error:

```
No se puede iniciar la aplicación. Falta el archivo de información del grupo de trabajo o bien está abierto en modo exclusivo por otro usuario.
```

He buscado en internet e insisten en que tengo abierta la BD en cuestión pero no es así. ¿alguna idea de qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Mira si [esto te sirve](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/8d4c2cbd-c669-49f7-8ba6-79039f1a7d7c/error-de-conexin-a-base-de-datos-en-access-2007-cifrada?forum=netfxes)

Comment: De hecho sí ha servido

Comment: Esa era la idea :) ....